# Empty sessions file created with Apache

Tags: php, apache, session, apache2, session-timeout

I'm stuck on a very big problem with my session files.
On the top of each php files needing an authentication I added that :

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 5*3600*24*365);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5*3600*24*365);
ini_set('session.save_path', __DIR__.'/sessions');
session_start();
```

So basically I changed the sessions directory because else in /tmp, I had some issue with the garbage collector which was cleaning my sessions.

But now I have a LOT of empty session files created when users are visiting my website.
When I said a lot, it reach 4 000 000 files in about one week with 30 000 unique visitors.

I'm using php 5.3.28 and Apache 2.2.26 on a Linux machine

Thank you for your help !

Comment: do you using session_destroy(); in your scripts?

Comment: Yes but only when people choose to disconnect

Comment: 5*3600*24*365 is for five years... So it have life for five years

Comment: yes I know, but why there are EMPTY session files ?
There are also all the valid session files in the sessions/ directory but definitly more empty files than valid ones

Comment: unset / destroy it ll remove content but it ll be deleted after 5 years

Comment: The problem is that i use destroy only on disconnect  and my system seems to create one empty session file for almost each page visited

Comment: session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor are the responsible for session garbage collection, you can check that values...

Comment: i realize this is old, but I'm experiencing the same thing and this still has no answer. about every second a blank session file is created. I have `session.gc_probability = 1`, `session.gc_divisor = 1`, and `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440`. the session directory gets loaded very quickly with blank sessions. idk if GC is taking care of them at all, or if maybe theyre being created too fast for it to keep up